# Country based categories, internationalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

We have an international site. On the top menu we want to show a list of country based categories. Some of these categories might coincide with others in other countries. Other won't.

I'm trying to come up with the best possible solution for this. We started by declaring locale files, but I think it is not the best solution as they're not words that will be used along all countries.

I'm thinking of making a helper that makes the menu based on the locale.

Example/use case:

User goes to **www.mysite.com/en** and sees following sub-menu (besides login/home elements):

- Professional Training
- Higher education
- High school

Then another user goes to **www.mysite.com/es** and sees the following:

- Formación profesional
- Educación superior
- Instituto
- Oposiciones

Note that depending on locale the sub-menu changes (and shares) some elements.

My questions:

> 1. Is it right to discard locale .yml for this purpose?
> 2. Is there any other way besides what I proposed?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you describe user scenario you want?

Comment: @borjagvo, what steps did you make from this [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to use localized views? This  [section of  the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#localized-views) explains how to use them.

In short: you could create a category partial for each country and add categories (with translated labels) accordingly. The downside is, that you have to maintain more partials.